# What is ubiquity?

Tags: ubiquity

Where is Ubiquity used in Ubuntu?

Comment: RelatedL [What software does the Ubuntu installer run on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/878641/what-software-does-the-ubuntu-installer-run-on), [What is the package name for the Ubuntu installation wizard?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110170/what-is-the-package-name-for-the-ubuntu-installation-wizard)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the wizard you see that installs Ubuntu. It also handles the slideshow in the package 'ubiquity-slideshow' which is made from HTML files.

Comment: ubiquity-slideshow renders using webkit

Answer (score 2):

It is the installer program.

Comment: More specifically, it's the installer that you encounter when installing the operating itself. Not to be confused with the package manager, which is what is being used for installing applications.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [Ubiquity Firefox Extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubiquity_%28Firefox%29), the project is halted by Mozilla Labs right now.
It is like a Gnome-Do for Firefox.

Comment: I was talking about the ubuntu installer.