# What is the package name for the Ubuntu installation wizard?

Tags: launchpad, bug-reporting, ubiquity

I need to log a bug against the 12.04 installer (the installation wizard that you run off the CD/DVD). What is the package name for this application?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The name of the installation wizard is `ubiquity`.

Linked Question:

- [What is ubiquity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1076/what-is-ubiquity)