# What software does the Ubuntu installer run on?

Tags: system-installation

Sorry if somebody has already asked this question, I haven't found anything else.

When you install Ubuntu, some sort of program is run, like where you set different options for your OS installation. 
Does anyone know what the software is being run?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this really a duplicate? [What is the package name for the Ubuntu installation wizard?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110170/what-is-the-package-name-for-the-ubuntu-installation-wizard) is a narrow question asking just for the package *name*. It's possible to interpret these questions as the same, but the answers here (mine and PIlot6's) are very different from the one there; both our answers actually explain what Ubiquity is. Because this is not specifically asking the name, I think it is the broader question; perhaps that one should be closed as a duplicate of this one, instead.

Comment: @EliahKagan voted the other way now.

Answer (score 4):

As [Pilot6 says](https://askubuntu.com/a/878644/22949), when you install Ubuntu using the graphical installer in a live environment, the installer you are using is [**Ubiquity**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubiquity). The [*desktop*](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) ISO images, which are the most popular way to install Ubuntu, use Ubiquity. (See also, [What is ubiquity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1076/what-is-ubiquity?rq=1).)

In contrast, when you install Ubuntu using the text-based [*server*](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/install-ubuntu-server), [*minimal*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD), or -- for [older releases that had them](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2012-August/035675.html) -- the [*alternate*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#Alternate_Installation) ISO image, that uses the [Debian installer](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller). More precisely, it is "**d-i**," which is the Debian installer with the necessary changes for Ubuntu.

As the [Installer/Development](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Installer/Development) page on the [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/) (by ["Contributors to the Ubuntu documentation wiki"](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/License)) says:

> Ubuntu and its various flavours (Kubuntu, Edubuntu, Xubuntu) have two
>   installers. One is a modified version of the [Debian installer](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller),
>   known as "d-i", and is written in POSIX shell script and C. The other,
>   Ubiquity, is used on our live CD (or "desktop CD"), features a
>   from-scratch user interface design, and has a good deal of front-end
>   code written in Python, but behind the scenes still uses d-i code for
>   many back-end tasks where it's important that we don't end up
>   maintaining two implementations.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I'll look more into it when I'm on my PC. (I'm on phone atm).

Answer (score 3):

This is `ubiquity`.

> Ubiquity is a simple graphical live CD installer designed to integrate
>   well with Debian- and Ubuntu-based systems, written largely in Python,
>   using d-i as a backend for many of its functions for ease of
>   maintenance.

<sup>— [Ubiquity](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubiquity), in the [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/), by ["Contributors to the Ubuntu documentation wiki"](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/License)</sup>

Comment: Like, Linux mint and other Ubuntu forks run the same installer right?

Comment: I don't know what other forks run. It is off-topic.

Comment: @MrKaKisen nope.