# Create iso instalation image of configured Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, iso

I am trying to create an image of my cofigured Ubuntu. I used System Back and Remastersys, but the problem is that the image created is a live image, it works on USB or VM, but I cannot install it on an empty OS.

Somebody has any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Yes the idea is: get a live dvd download. Chroot it. edit the live dvd to include all your changes, create the ISO and then burn it. Took me about 3 weeks to get it all as I wanted. Here is my answer on that: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd Though outdated the general idea is still the same. I would say: what you want is time consuming. It is quicker to just install your normal system and create a post-install script to remove, add software and to create files for settings.

Comment: Is there any answers relavant to ubuntiu 20?

Answer (score 1):

You must include the installer packages into your ISO image. It is called [Ubiquity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1076/what-is-ubiquity) on Ubuntu ISO images for Desktop releases (I assume your Ubuntu is Desktop version).

The reason you can't find these packages on already installed system, is because these packages are only needed on Live images (Live CD/DVD/USB). In fact, the installer packages will be removed from the local system, where Ubuntu had been installed.

Additionally, you can also read the difference (also mentioned different installers) used for the Desktop, Server and Alternate installs on [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17952/what-are-the-differences-between-desktop-server-and-alternate-installs) instead.